# java.net.UnknownHostException: api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp

Tags: java, unknown-host, amazon-pay

We are testing the Amazon Payment Java SDK application at our local environment. On starting the application, `Login with Amazon sandbox` button gets displayed. On clicking that, we enter Amazon account user and password, after which I'm getting below exception. I'm novice at how Amazon Payment works. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**nslook** gives me following result:

```
Server:  aadc1.alpha.local
Address:  192.168.1.21    
Name:    api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp
```

**dig** gives me following result:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.0-P2 <<>> api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 54139
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 20b58299d9088b57 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp.      IN      A

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.21#53(192.168.1.21)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 26 15:52:43 ???? (?W???) 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

The stack trace is as below:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.amazon.payments.paywithamazon.impl.Util.httpSendRequest(Util.java:95) ~[pay-with-amazon-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.payments.paywithamazon.impl.Util.httpSendRequest(Util.java:148) ~[pay-with-amazon-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.amazon.payments.paywithamazon.impl.PaymentsClient.getUserInfo(PaymentsClient.java:919) ~[pay-with-amazon-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at jp.ambc.amazonpayments.AmazonPayments.getUserInfo(AmazonPayments.java:44) ~[bin/:na]
    at jp.ambc.amazonpayments.AmazonPaymentsController.auth(AmazonPaymentsController.java:33) ~[bin/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `nslookup` or `dig` on that address from the command line?

Comment: I'm getting details like server name, address and name on ding nslookup.

Comment: Edit your post and include the console output (copy/paste, format as code) of those two commands.

Comment: Your internal DNS is broken. Talk to your local network admin.  We cannot help you beyond that recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS server you are using (`192.168.1.21`) does not appear to be correctly configured.

Try

```
dig @8.8.8.8 api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp
```

You should get back something like this:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.4 <<>> @8.8.8.8 api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59419
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.sandbox.amazon.co.jp. 899   IN      CNAME   api-sandbox.amazon.co.jp.
api-sandbox.amazon.co.jp. 59    IN      A       54.240.252.254

;; Query time: 111 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 25 22:59:47 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

where the important part is the two lines in the ANSWER section. The first is the CNAME giving the canonical hostname (`api-sandbox.amazon.co.jp`) and the second is the IP address of that host.

Then talk to whoever administers the DNS server (it is local within your organization) to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the inputs!